# Does the order of include statement in settings.gradle matter?

Tags: gradle

Any difference between this?
Settings.gradle

Case A:

```
include ':con', ':conlib', 'aaa:test'
```

vs Case B:

```
include 'aaa:test'  
include ':con'
include ':conlib',
```

No difference? 
or Is it effects to build order or something?

Comment: I already know the dependency can be set in module's build.grade file.
but I don't get it in settings.gradle file.

Comment: Matter for what?

Comment: Currently I don't find any matter, but if there are... 
and I just like to know about the difference of statements

Comment: "Tell me of a problem that I don't know about" is not even a question.

Answer (score 1):

no, order (probably) does not matter. to be clear, this is an educated guess, after following the docs link I didn't learn much, but there are three reasons this has to be true:

**1) changing the order of `include()` calls does not invalidate build caches.** this is a good hint that the Gradle team does not see the order of include statements as important.

**2) the docs do not stipulate a required or meaningful order.** at least that i can tell from the available links.

**3) `buildSrc` is compiled after `settings.gradle[.kts]`.** anytime after Gradle 6 (see [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/11090)), `buildSrc` is compiled *after* `settings.gradle.kts`, and `buildSrc` is made available in your build. It stands to reason, then, that the order of `include()` calls *cannot* matter, because if they did, it would transitively require a rebuild of your `buildSrc`, which would invalidate your entire build.

again, just educated guesses based on observations, i hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

The impact of ordering of `include {submodule_name}` can be found out in the [Gradle doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:dependencies_which_dependencies).

But it should be also noted that it has to be `{submodule_name}` not `{submodule_name}:{gardle_task}` (like `aaa:test`).

Comment: It would be helpful if you summarized here what the impact is, since the docs are terrible (and that's what StackOverflow is for)